# Regex negative lookbehinds with a wildcard

Tags: ruby, regex, lookbehind

I'm trying to match some text if it does not have another block of text in its vicinity. For example, I would like to match `"bar"` if `"foo"` does not precede it. I can match `"bar"` if `"foo"` does not *immediately* precede it using negative look behind in this regex:

```
/(?<!foo)bar/
```

but I also like to not match `"foo 12345 bar"`. I tried:

```
/(?<!foo.{1,10})bar/
```

but using a  wildcard + a range appears to be an invalid regex in Ruby. Am I thinking about the problem wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are thinking about it the right way. But unfortunately lookbehinds usually have be of fixed-length. The only major exception to that is .NET's regex engine, which allows repetition quantifiers inside lookbehinds. But since you only need a negative lookbehind and not a lookahead, too. There is a hack for you. Reverse the string, then try to match:

```
/rab(?!.{0,10}oof)/
```

Then reverse the result of the match or subtract the matching position from the string's length, if that's what you are after.

Now from the regex you have given, I suppose that this was only a simplified version of what you actually need. Of course, if `bar` is a complex pattern itself, some more thought needs to go into how to reverse it correctly.

Note that if your pattern required both variable-length lookbehinds and lookaheads, you would have a harder time solving this. Also, in your case, it would be possible to deconstruct your lookbehind into multiple variable length ones (because you use neither `+` nor `*`):

```
/(?<!foo)(?<!foo.)(?<!foo.{2})(?<!foo.{3})(?<!foo.{4})(?<!foo.{5})(?<!foo.{6})(?<!foo.{7})(?<!foo.{8})(?<!foo.{9})(?<!foo.{10})bar/
```

But that's not all that nice, is it?

Comment: Reversing the string was an interesting idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As m.buettner already mentions, lookbehind in Ruby regex has to be of fixed length, and is described so in the document. So, you cannot put a quantifier within a lookbehind.

You don't need to check all in one step. Try doing multiple steps of regex matches to get what you want. Assuming that existence of `foo` in front of a single instance of `bar` breaks the condition regardless of whether there is another `bar`, then

```
string.match(/bar/) and !string.match(/foo.*bar/)
```

will give you what you want for the example.

If you rather want the match to succeed with `bar foo bar`, then you can do this

```
string.scan(/foo|bar/).first == "bar"
```

Comment: That is problematic if the idea is to actually retrieve a match. Say you have have `bar foo bar`. The regex that the OP tried would retrieve the first `bar`. Your solution would claim that there is no match. (Apart from the fact that you omitted the "up to 10 characters" heuristic)

Comment: @m.buettner You and I have different interpretations with the question.

Comment: Sure. Which is why I don't say your solution is wrong. But I find it important that such assumptions and differences are stated. Because they might not be apparent to the OP or anyone else who finds this question in the future.

Comment: Thanks for articulating the different interpretations. I'm accepting @m.buettner's response as it was what I needed